# Clone an HTML page except divs of a specified class

Tags: jquery

It's easy to clone your HTML file with jQuery:

```
alert($("html").clone().html());
```

My goal is to clone the whole program except divs of class '.ignore' but the best I can do is display ONLY those divs.

```
// This displays the inverse of what I want: just the code to be removed
alert($("html").clone().find('.ignore').remove().html());

// Seems to have the exact same effect as above:
alert($("html").clone().find('.ignore').html());
```

What's the best way to obtain all but the specified div class?

Comment: Use `.filter()`: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Actually, this should be enough: `$('body :not(.ignore)').clone()`

Comment: Why not simply `$("html").clone().remove('.ignore');`

Comment: @Floris your suggestion won't work. Plus OP is looking for html and not object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [`.end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) function

```
alert($("html").clone().find('.ignore').remove().end().html());
```

A working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sh99ognm/

Comment: That worked! Holy cow! If you saw the gyrations I went through not getting the answer, you'd take away my jQuery privileges. Thanks so much.

Comment: Haha, glad I could help. I find that whenever I'm over-complicating code, I'm usually just overlooking a simple jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a filter in the selector.

This will return a new object containing the whole page filtered:

```
$(function () {
    var newContent = $('body :not(.ignore)').clone(); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/Ls0arfhr/1/)

This will retrieve the filtered `html` and append it back to the `body`:

```
$(function () {
    var newContent = $('body :not(.ignore)').clone(); 

    $('body').empty();

    newContent.each(function () {
        $('body').append($(this));
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/Ls0arfhr/2/)

You could also use `.filter()`:

```
$(function () {    
    var newContent = $('body > *').clone().filter(':not(.ignore)', function () {
        return $(this).html();
    }); 

    $('body').html(newContent);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/Ls0arfhr/3/)